# Can you unlock Google Marketplace applications through in app purchases

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

Can someone create an application A for Android devices that contains functionality to unlock applications B and C in the marketplace?

Keep in mind that applications B and C should be purchasable by alternative means (aka actually buying them in them market place) but ALSO available in the secondary method inside application A.

This would create a system where users could unlock content via spending time in the application A (perhaps working towards some form of currency) that they could spend on real applications. Application A would also serve to advertise those applications B and C possibly getting players to choose to buy them rather than earn them, or get friends of players to buy said games.

Answer (score 0):

It would not be possible. And if it were through some back door method, I doubt the downloads would show, so it wouldn't likely help the apps rating.

If you were a skilled hacker, you might be able to figure it out, but of course that would not be recommended.

> I guess a more indirect way of doing it, although not nearly as
>   enticing, would be to distribute apps B and C for free, but require a
>   registration code that is unlockable via an inapp purchase, or via in
>   app purchase from app A ???

That would be a good way to do it, but you would need a good way to manage the code, so the user won't easily loose it. For example, back up data on google servers: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html
And/or send the user an email that has their activation code, I guess.

Also, you could distribute a paid app that would just act as a key for apps B and C on the market and then the key could be purchased instead of using the in-app purchase.: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html

Or, you could make apps B and C both have paid versions that are the full app and free versions that are the lite version, and then use in-app purchases or your code idea to upgrade from the lite version to the pro version.

Comment: I guess a more indirect way of doing it, although not nearly as enticing, would be to distribute apps B and C for free, but require a registration code that is unlockable via an inapp purchase, or via in app purchase from app A ???